# Html title best practices and usage (wp_title, title-tag support, etc..)?

Tags: wp-title

I really can't get the right practices from official docs. I think it's a complete mess.

At some point, they started to say to activate the title-tag feature: after_setup_theme >

```
add_theme_support('title-tag');
```

- Ok. At this point they stated we should delete the `<title>` tag from page and stop using `wp_title()`. Perfect.
- So we had to use the `'wp_title'` filter to modify our titles. Right. I did, that worked, once upon a time.
- Then they said '`'wp_title'` filter was deprecated, and we should have used `pre_get_document_title` and other filters. Wow, great. Currently they seem not to work, though.
- Then they said '`'wp_title'` filter was *'reinstated until alternative usages have been identified and a path forward for them defined'* Sexy.

But if I look into the core code, I can see that the 'title-tag' has no filters to modify its output. So if I want custom coded texts inside my titles, should I use wp_title() again and disable 'title-tag' support?

Really, can someone shed a definitive light on this topic?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any SEO plugins installed? They usually fiddle with this logic. Having Yoast enabled, the `pre_get_document_title` does not work for me, instead you should use `wpseo_title` [per their documentation](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/).

Having said that, with SEO plugins disabled and `add_theme_support('title-tag');` enabled, the `pre_get_document_title` filter works for me without any problem.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', function () {
    add_theme_support('title-tag');
}, 20);

add_filter('pre_get_document_title', function ($title) {
    return 'ORO!';
});
```

Result is, that I see `ORO!` as the page title.

Comment: That's interesting.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can say, currently for me the best option is the old school `wp_title()` thing: that will work. So:

- Do not add `title-tag` theme sopport
- Keep your `<title><?php wp_title([whatever options]) ?></title>` on page
- If you need further customisations, feel free to use the `wp_title` filter > it's not deprecated and will correctly work.

Until the next wp messy recommendations..